# Sed script to remove first two lines of file if they are empty

Tags: perl, sed, pattern-matching

I'm trying to write a fairly concise sed script to remove the first two lines of a file **only if** they are empty, so the following file:

```
> cat myfile.in


Line 3

Line 5
```

Would result in a three line output file:

```
> cat myfile.out
Line 3

Line 5
```

This involves combining line ranges and pattern matching and I just can't seem to find any examples of that. I'd also be intersted if anyone could suggest and equally (or more) consise Perl alternative. Many thanks.

**Footnote**

I should add that I tried `1,2{/^$/d}` which worked absolutely fine on Linux, but under AIX I got:

```
sed: 0602-404 Function 1,2{/^$/d} cannot be parsed.
```

and on Solaris I got:

```
sed: command garbled: 1,2{/^$/d}
```

Which is a blow because this code has to run on both AIX and Solaris, but not Linux! Shame!

Comment: How do spaces and tabs work out here? (Is your criteria identical to _delete the first two characters if they are newlines_?)

Comment: @sarnold: I am assuming that there will not be an spaces or tabs but would like any solution to make extending this to cover them easy to do, as in changing `/^$/` to `/^[ \t]*$/`

Comment: What is the desired behavior if the first line is empty but the second is not?

Comment: @cjm: Blank lines should be removed only within the line range 1,2. Therefore any combination of line 1 and line 2 can be removed if they are individually empty - they don't *both* have to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work with sed (if you want to delete both first lines if both are empty):

```
sed '1,1{N;/^\n$/d}'
```

i.e.: `1,1` = goto first line, `N` = append next line to pattern space, `^\n$/d` = delete those two lines if they are empty.

If you want to delete the first two lines if they are empty (independently from the other line) you could do:

```
sed '1,2/^$/d'
```

Comment: Ticked this as I like the conciseness of it, but I really need to consider the two lines individually rather than combined. Sorry if I did not make this clear. Also, although this worked fine under Linux, it did not AIX (see the Footnote I've added above.) but gave me `sed: 0602-404 Function 1,1{N;/^\n$/d} cannot be parsed.` Thanks.

Comment: The range `1,1` is not necessary, `1` is suffice. For some reason to cater for all weird and wonderful sed versions `$!N` seems to be the standard. So sed `1{$!N;/^\n$/d}' would fit the bill (OSX/bsd might disagree).

Comment: Sorry - I don't have AIX to try. On Solaris 8 I have a problem, too. I will try to find a solution.

Comment: @potong: Yes. I understood the OP's first comment to my answer this way.

Answer (score 9):

Here's one way to do it in Perl:

```
perl -ne 'print if $. > 2 or $_ ne "\n"' <myfile.in >myfile.out
```

If you want to allow additional whitespace on your empty lines:

```
perl -ne 'print if $. > 2 or /\S/' <myfile.in >myfile.out
```

This next version does something a bit different.  It removes only initial blank lines (up to 2).  If the first line is not blank, but the second is, both lines will be printed.  (I thought of it before you replied to my comment, and I like it, and the next person who happens across this question might have different requirements.)

```
perl -ne 'print if $started ||= $. > 2 || /\S/'
```

The `$started ||=` means that once printing starts, it won't stop.

Answer (score 3):

Not a perl monk, but I would do this in Perl (probably there is a better way):

```
$_ = <> or exit 0; print unless /^\s*$/;
$_ = <> or exit 0; print unless /^\s*$/;
print while <>;
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be done in a simple awk script like this:

```
awk 'NR>2 || $0 != ""' file.txt
```

**EDIT:** Since awk wasn't considered an accepted tool to solve the problem here is one sed command that works on Mac and Linux both:

```
sed '/^$/{1,2d;}' file.txt
```

OR

```
sed '1,2s/^$/~@#%-=/; /^~@#%-=$/d' file.txt
```

Assuming file doesn't have a `~@#%-=` line (which can be changed to any other arbitrary text).

Comment: Thanks, but I really need to know how this can be acheived in sed or perl.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that `1,2{/^$/d}` will work on Linux but not on AIX or Solaris. However `/^$/{1,2d;}` seems to work on all three platforms so giving precedence to pattern matching rather than number ranges seems to be important.

Comment: That's correct, I posted `/^$/{1,2d;}`after testing myself on Linux, Mac and cygwin.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
sed -e '1{/^$/d}' -e '2{/^$/d}' file
```

Comment: @anubhava `sed -n 'l;2q' file` will show what sed is seeing, I don't use a Mac so I can't test.

Comment: That is printing `$` twice as `$
$`

Comment: @anubhava `$` means end of line so what does `sed -n '$!N;l;q'` show?

Comment: That also prints same output that is 2 `$` in separate lines. btw I posted one sed solution in my answer that worked on Mac and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **`ed`** text editor:

```
$ echo -e '1,2g/^$/d\n%p' | ed -s input.txt
```

If you want to save the result:(change **`%p`** to **`w`**)

```
$ echo -e '1,2g/^$/d\nw' | ed -s input.txt
```

Answer (score -3):

You can do it in awk this way

```
cat 1.txt | awk '{if(NR>2){print $0;}}'
```

Comment: No, that just removes the first two lines of the file, whether they are empty or not.

Comment: It works only if the first two lines are empty.  If they're not empty, it removes them anyway.  But the question said to remove only blank lines.